# Does keys in ListProperty properties get converted properly when migrating to HR datastore on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

We're migrating to the HR datastore. We can't find this in the docs and want to make sure it'll work.

We have a few properties defined as:

```
ListProperty(db.Key)
```

Will those keys migrate normally? (they're not strings, they're db.Keys)

Same goes for

```
ListProperty(SomeAwesomeCustomModel)
```

Will those get migrated normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListProperty(db.Key) gets migrated just like KeyProperty().

I'm not sure how you could have ListProperty(SomeAwesomeCustomModel) -- ListProperty() only supports a limited list of types, not Model subclasses.